# Text to Speech Custom Rate (beyond slider)

Tags: terminal, customization, text-to-speech

In System Preferences, under Dictation & Speech, there is a Speaking Rate setting:

[image]

Is there a way to change the Speaking Rate to a value that is not on that slider bar?

For example, if I want the speech rate to be faster than the maximum slider value, how can I do that? There's a way to make the terminal speak certain lines of text faster (e.g. say --rate 500 "hello world"), but I'd like it to be the system-wide setting.

Could someone walk me through how to do this step by step?